# NodeJS generate excel file from binary data, can not be opened in Excel

Tags: java, node.js, excel, binary

I am lost in this solution.
1. Excel file is saved in server;
2. Using Java API to read the excel file as binary data. Here is the function:

```
@Override
public byte[] retrieveExportedFileBinaryContent(String recordId, String userId) throws IOException, NoExportRecordException, InValidDownloadPermissionException{
    CaseExportRecord caseExportRecord = caseExportRecordRepository.findById(recordId);
    if( caseExportRecord!=null ){

        CaseExportConfig caseExportConfig = caseExportConfigRepository.findByCaseExportRecords(caseExportRecord);

        if(caseExportConfig.getUserId().equalsIgnoreCase(userId)){
            String fileName = generateExportedFileNameWithPath(caseExportRecord);
            Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
             if( path!=null ){
                 return Files.readAllBytes(path);
             }else{
                 throw new NoExportRecordException("Case Export Record File Does Not Exist");
             }
        } else {
            throw new InValidDownloadPermissionException("You do not have permission to download this file.");
        }


    }else{
        throw new NoExportRecordException("Case Export Record Id Not Exist");
    }
}
```

3. using NodeJS to obtain the binary data and create an excel file:

   ```
   var fs = require('fs');
       var wstream = fs.createWriteStream('my.xls');
       wstream.write(fileData);
       wstream.end();
   ```

Here fileData is the binary data returned by Java API.

But now, when I use Excel to open this xls file, it is no longer the good excel and only raw binary data is displayed in excel.

How can I create a good excel file from binary data?

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to read the excel file manually, wondering if the file is written write using NodeJS code and not corrupt.

Comment: Problem of intercross plaform. java concepts are totally different from Nde.js . What u r doing is convert the whole file as a row byte using java but writing it using node.js (which is not native to java). so all raw bytes will be write to a file and only because u defined a (.xls) extension. it will open in Excel but not in proper format as u want bcoz Node.js doesn't know the what kind of data format node is receiving. so it will write `rowdata` bytes to the file but not the actual format..

Thank You

Comment: You are right, so, any good suggestion on how to use nodeJS create an excel from binary data? I really don't see any good solution. Perhaps I have to use csv file and then use nodeJS to create excel based on csv, low efficient and kind of stupid solution.